# Foodmart schema not showing on Pentaho

Tags: datasource, pentaho

I'm studying pentaho using [this guide](http://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-2/), but I'm having a problem showing the foodmart schema on the Schema drop down menu, both inside the Pentaho analysis and inside the Saiku analysis.

What do I have to do to make it work?

Further details can be provided upon asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work. Turns out my version of Pentaho didn't come with foodmart.montrian.xml 
I downloaded it [here](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-565) and put it inside `pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/foodmart`

Answer (score 0):

check the logs when pentaho/saiku start. See if there's an error validating the schema.
Also check that system/olap/datasources.xml is setup correctly.
what is your build? it's included in the downloadable demo, so you must have something different?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about saiku in the logs. In the datasources.xml I have only two catalogs registered, those being SteelWheels and SampleData.